# Connection is invalid error when running Applescript and Safari

Tags: macos, safari, applescript, script

The following applescript waits for a page to load before continuing with the `do javascript "document.body.innerText"` part of the script. It seems to work really well except for one thing. If Safari is running but no window is currently open, running this script results in

> error "Safari got an error: Connection is invalid." number -609

Yet if I run this when Safari is closed it launches Safari, goes to the specified URL and once the page loads, runs the javascript portion. I don't understand why it gets an error if Safari is running with no windows open.

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    if not (exists document 1) then reopen
    tell front document
        set URL to "http://example.com"
        repeat until length of (source as text) is not 0
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
        do javascript "document.body.innerText"
    end tell
end tell
```

The error always highlights the `source as text` part of the script. I tried changing `length of (source as text) is not 0` to `repeat until name is "example domain"` but the error still occurs if no windows are open and Safari is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to swap the position of the `activate` line of *code* with the `if not (exists document 1) then reopen` line of *code*.

Example:

```
tell application "Safari"
    if not (exists document 1) then reopen
    activate
    tell front document
        set URL to "http://example.com"
        repeat until length of (source as text) is not 0
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
        do javascript "document.body.innerText"
    end tell
end tell
```

---

The screenshot of the Script Editor, below, was run with Safari open and without any windows opened.

[image: Script Editor window]

First I had to check "[√] Show Develop menu in menu bar" (Safari > Preferences… > Advanced) and then on the Develop menu click "Allow JavaScript from Apple Events". Next I copied and pasted your AppleScript *code* in Script Editor and clicked the *Run the Script* button and it ran without error and returned the text of the http://example.com web page. However Safari was closed when I ran the script the first time.

After reading your question again, I was able to reproduce the error by having Safari open without any windows open.  I then looked more throughly at your *code* and noticed `activate` was before `if not (exists document 1) then reopen` and `activate` needs to be after it to avoid the error.

Comment: Having `activate` in the wrong place never even crossed my mind. Works perfectly now. Thank you for solving yet another of my Apple related questions.

Answer (score -1):

Reseting my preferences file fixed this for me. To do that, hold down Command+Option+Control+Shift keys while opening Indesign application.

Indesign version 15.0.1
Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: Thanks for the down vote and the non-explanation of said down vote. This actually did work for me.

Comment: My guess would be, as the question is about **AppleScript** and **Safari**, what does **Indesign** and pressing the Command+Option+Control+Shift keys have to do with the question asked!? Did you by chance post your answer to the wrong question?

Comment: Don't let downvotes get you down (no pun intended). It's just the internet. ;) Although, I'm not sure what Indesign has to do with the question.